# Pointers and local variables

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, scope

I was given this code in an exam, and needed to explain what it does:
(I changed some names, since the source was not English)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int typeInfoSCL;
struct elemSCL
{
    typeInfoSCL info;
    struct elemSCL* next;
};

typedef struct elemSCL TypeElemSCL;
typedef TypeElemSCL* TypeSCL;

void list_add(TypeSCL *scl, typeInfoSCL e)
{
    TypeSCL tmp = *scl;
    *scl = malloc(sizeof(struct elemSCL));
    (*scl)->info = e;
    (*scl)->next = tmp;
}

int main()
{
    TypeSCL scl1 = NULL;
    list_add(&scl1, 3);
    list_add(&scl1, 5);
    TypeSCL tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct elemSCL));
    tmp->next = scl1;
    list_add(&tmp, 7);
}
```

I thought that since `tmp` is a local variable in `list_add`, this statement:

```
(*scl)->next = tmp;
```

would be incorrect, since after the method is invoked, `scl->next` no longer exists.

Tests proved me wrong. Why is that so?

Comment: This code does not compile, please post compilable code. You probably didn't change all names properly.

Comment: Since this is some kind of pseudo code and not real C, it is impossible to answer the question. In particular, the missing return type of the function makes all the difference to any attempt to answer.

Comment: I assume you missed some `*` here: `struct elemSCL next;`

Comment: Even if this was code from an exam, please don't make it a habit for yourself to make type-aliases (using `typedef`) of pointers (like `TypeSCL`). It obfuscates what the type really is and makes the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: And in the future it's okay to have functions or variables with non-English names. Instead concentrate on copy the code as verbatim as possible, or if it's code in a file then just copy-paste it. Add comments in the code explaining what the non-English names might stand for if it's not obvious.

Comment: 1) C does not support _methods_. 2) Please provide a reference to the C standard defining "sgementation fault" and why the code should generate it.

Comment: Can you be specific about how you tested this?  I'm guessing you ran the program under Valgrind's Memcheck, but you don't specifically say, and I wanted to make sure that you know that the runtime isn't required to diagnose undefined behaviours!

Answer (score 2):

While the variable `tmp` is a local variable, with the assignment

```
(*scl)->next = tmp;
```

you don't make `(*scl)->next` point to the *variable*, instead you just copy the contents of `tmp` (which is the location of where it is pointing) into `(*scl)->next`.

After the assignment you have two pointers (`(*scl)->next` and `tmp`) both pointing to the same memory. When the function returns and `tmp` goes out of scope `(*scl)->next` will still keep its value and continue to point to the same memory.

Comment: Don't you think that because `struct elemSCL` has a member `struct elemSCL` and not `struct elemSCL *`, the program will eventually go out of memory when we create an variable of type `struct elemSCL` ? I mean this should also be one of the issue.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS I assume there are a lot of typos in the shown code because of the OP's "translation". The main point still stands, that the pointers are copied just like any other assignment between variables.